# Flex - scroll wheel ok using IE, but not on FF or Chrome?

Tags: apache-flex, flash

Flex - scroll wheel ok using IE, but not on FF or Chrome?

Switching between browsers during debugging and noticed the scroll wheel does not work in Firefox or Chrome, but is fine in Internet Explorer. Anyone else notice this? Suppose I could use a scroll listener and manually do it, but would much rather not!

Comment: You might want to consider using MacMouseWheel (http://blog.pixelbreaker.com/flash/as30-mousewheel-on-mac-os-x), especially if you're already using SWFObject (http://www.swfobject.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the cause of problem or not . but sometimes in flex when you run a project in your default testing browser . the recent changes doesn't show themselves . but when you copy the address of that file and paste it to another browser , it just works fine . if you're default browser doesn't show your project properly , the cause of problem is probably that .

Comment: Its not this, but good suggestion. You can also change your debug browser in Winow>Preferences>General>WebBrowser, save you copying and pasting the address.

Answer (score 1):

Some versions of Chrome use it's own Pepper Flash player plugin which makes these nasty things with mouse wheel.
I created a small lib which works with all types of flash plugins AND on OS-x
[GITHUB repo](https://github.com/KumoKairo/BlastedMouseWheelBlock)